# hide scrollbars iFrame child website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

Using Colorbox jquery plugin, I use the iFrame popup class to display websites. Usually this works just fine, except when the website I am opening has larger than normal width. If that happens, The website will show horizontal scrollbars.

Here is the Colorbox code I use in my `<Head>`

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){  
$(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"100%", height:"90%", scrolling: false});     
</script>
```

Here is the link I use to open website

```
<a class="iframe" href="client.php?id=<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>&Client Name=<?php echo $rows['client_name'] ?>">
```

If the website that opens is pretty standard dimensions, there will be no scrollbars or anything which is perfect. If the website it opens is very wide, it will show scrollbars and look bad. I would like to hide the scrollbars no matter what.

[Here is an Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EBtB.jpg)

Is there any to hide scrollbar in this situation? I tried inspecting with chrome, but  when I try adding a `Overflow: hidden` to IFRAME element, it does NOT hide.

Comment: Try `overflow-y: none` as well. If that doesn't work, unfortunately there's no way to solve it as there's no way to access cross domain content inside an `iframe`. If it does work, though, be aware that part of the inner website content will be unaccessible inside the `iframe`.

Comment: @lucasnadalutti why not do it like this? https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/7oe5kh9L/27/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
<iframe src="https://css-tricks.com" width="100" height="100" style="overflow-y: hidden;" seamless="seamless" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

add `style="overflow-y: hidden;" seamless="seamless" scrolling="no"` to your `<iframe>`

See fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/7oe5kh9L/27/